# PHP Cronjob with CPanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I've never set a Cronjob before.

Is it enough to just write the php file I want to execute (in this case send a mail every 24h) and follow through the CPanel GUI prompts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, that is all you have to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a screenshot that shows sample usage of cPanel's Cron Job UI:

http://screencast.com/t/MDc5MTJkMGQ

Comment: Thank you. (character limit is annoying all I want to say is "Thank you.")